# TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'item'

Tags: python, lambda

I cant seem to figure out what the problem is here.i'm using this code to create multiple groups of numbers from an array.i'm not sure if it is a python compatibility issue or not.

```py
data=[]
data=1,2,3,4,6,7,8,11,12
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda i, x: i-x):
    print map(itemgetter(1), g)
```

`<TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'`

Comment: Your `lambda i, x : i -x` expects two parameters, but a `groupby` works with a function that takes one parameter. You probably want to perform iterable unpacking.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is Python 2.x - you're just missing a pair of brackets around the `lambda`'s parameters:

```
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda (i, x): i-x):
    print map(itemgetter(1), g)
```

Comment: to further clarify: the `TypeError` is raised because a tuple is passed to the lambda, not 2 separate arguments (`enumerate` turns `[x]` into `[(i, x)]` and that `(i, x)` is passed to the lambda).

Answer (score 2):

You here defined with `lambda i, x : i - x` a function that takes two parameters, but the `groupby` function only takes one parameter. In this case a 2-tuple.

You thus can obtain the elements with *subscripting*:

```
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda x: x[0]-x[1]):
    print(map(itemgetter(1), g))
```

or in [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7), you can use *iterable unpacking*:

```
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda (i, x): i - x):
    print(map(itemgetter(1), g))
```

here we thus *unpack* the tuple in two parameters `i` and `x`.